# Android standard behavior for Emergency Call (911) or Emergency Call back Mode

Tags: android

I am trying to find out the standard Android M behavior during an Emergency Call (911) and also during an Emergency Call back mode (ECB).
Obviously I do not want to dial 911 from my phone risking getting arrested, how do I simulate this behavior?
Can anybody help and guide?

Comment: So you want to... programmatically call 911?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the emulator (Virtual Device), it can simulate a phone call, but not doing the real dialing.

Here is an official reference for [Android Virtual Device](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html)